# mplayer can't read from streamripper relay

Tags: streaming, mplayer

To use the same bandwidth for ripping and playing a stream I start a relay when ripping with streamripper :

```
$ streamripper -r link2stream
```

And to play it :

```
$ vlc http://localhost:8000
```

With vlc this works fine, but I want to use mplayer which doesn't work :

```
$ mplayer http://localhost:8000

Playing http://localhost:8000.
Resolving localhost for AF_INET...
Connecting to server localhost[127.0.0.1]: 8000...

Name   : ...
Website: ...
Cache size set to 320 KBytes
Cache fill: 19.31% (63270 bytes)   

Exiting... (End of file
```

Comment: Actually I'm using `cvlc <stream>` (the command line for vlc) instead of mplayer till I find a clue about this issue...